# Duplicate values in eclipse debugger

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm doing some debugging in eclipse and I find that I've got variables appearing twice, with the second appearance being null:

[image]

(I should say that class name is AbstractSyntaxTree because it builds an AST - not because it's declared abstract - although it does inherit form an abstract class...)

Can anyone tell me what might cause this? Is it something about the debugger or about my code?

Edit:  let's have a look at the code...

```
public class AbstractSyntaxTreeBuilder extends AbstractSyntaxTreeSuperclass {
  protected GLLHashPool parser;
  protected String input;
  protected TreeNode root;
  protected ArtTextHandler handler;


  public AbstractSyntaxTreeBuilder(String sourceString) {
    super(sourceString);
  }
...
```

..and the superclass:

```
public abstract class AbstractSyntaxTreeSuperclass {
  protected GLLHashPool parser;
  protected String input;
  protected TreeNode root;
  protected ArtTextHandler handler;


  public AbstractSyntaxTreeSuperclass(String sourceString) {
    super();
    handler = new ArtTextHandler();
    Text text = new Text(handler);
    parser = new ArtGrammarParser(text);
    input = sourceString;
....
```

Comment: Without seeing a sample of your code, it's difficult to rule out your code.

Comment: It's possible that your Class is redefining and hiding variables with the same name in the superclass.  So the variables in your class have  a value (since you set them) and the ones in the superclass are not set (the null values).

Comment: changeStack have duplicates variables?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - fair - have added...

Comment: If it's something wrong in the debugger you can use the best feature eclipse comes with. The restart button in the file menu...

Comment: So now it's clear that you have duplicate member variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the following from AbstractSyntaxTreeBuilder:

```
protected GLLHashPool parser;
  protected String input;
  protected TreeNode root;
  protected ArtTextHandler handler;
```

They are declared as protected in the super class (AbstractSyntaxTreeSuperclass) so the sub class (AbstractSyntaxTreeBuilder ) will have access to them.